# How to set the parameter values if it is NULL in query at run time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want get the records based on the following condition

```
String sql="select *from employee where email like "+student.email+" OR phoneno="+student.pno;
```

Sometimes email or phone, email only, phone only  may be null values in that case it will display all records if email and phone is null. if email only null then it will display the records based on phone no like this.

Any idea please ?

Comment: This looks like a code issue, not a MySQL issue. What language are you using? It looks like either Java or C#.

Comment: @valverij why do you say that? he is asking, please modify this query so that if someone doesn't give an email, it will return based on phone, if no phone is provided it will return based on email. If both are available, return based on both of them.

Comment: The only way this would match if email and phone were null, is if both your variables 'student.email' and 'student.pno' were also null.

Comment: @nrathaus, because then he might not have to modify the query at all. For example, if this were C#, he would be getting unexpected results because of the way .NET treats `null` in when converting it to SQL. Instead, he could use the C# coalesce operator `??` to pass in something like `student.email ?? DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF`:

```
String sql="SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE IF("+student.email+" IS NULL, 1, email = "+student.email+") OR
      IF("+student.pno+" IS NULL, 1, phoneno = "+student.pno+")";
```

I suggest to use binders, rather than direct value to SQL as it is prone to SQL injection also it will be safer overall with no funky characters causing issues.

Comment: I think student.email and student.pno are variables, not strings with plus signs?

Comment: I wrote a modification to the SQL without the surrounding code @JimBlack

Comment: For example, Javascript (or Java or C#), you would use '+' to create compound strings.  In his example, the '+' signs are outside of the double quotes, not inside.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying @JimBlack, I took his line and added the ``IF``, where is the error with that? my aim is the SQL not the code he is using. It could be pseudo code for all I know

Comment: I am using java if(pno.equals(null)&&email.equals(null)||pno.equals("")&&email.equals(""))
   {   
   sql="select *from aerp_marketing";
   }
   else if(email.equals(null)||email.equals("")){ 
   sql="select *from aerp_marketing where  phoneno like "+pno;
   }else if(pno.equals(null)||pno.equals("")){   
   sql="select *from aerp_marketing where email like '"+email+"'";
   System.out.println("SQL Qyery:"+sql);
   }else
    sql="select *from aerp_marketing where email like "+email+" and phoneno like "+pno;

Comment: Don't do it in Java (the check) make it inside your SQL, it will make it clearer to read and less prone to mistakes if someone else reads your code. Also with SQL ``IF`` you can take the SQL and test it without needing to read through the java and try to guess what SQL is being run

Comment: so far i am using this way only using if else condition or StringBuilder. i have no idea about another way please help me any one !!!!!!

Comment: I just wrote to you how to do it in SQL what is the issue? if you don't know SQL use Java to do the IF

Answer (score 0):

```
i tired with following code. now i am getting expected output exactly. any one 
can tell me another way . 

StringBuilder sql=new StringBuilder("select *from aerp_marketing");
        int i=0,k=0;
    if(!(pno.equals(null)||pno.equals("")))
        {
            i=1;k=1;
        sql.append(" mobileno like '"+pno+"'");
        }
        if(!(email.equals(null)||email.equals("")))
    {
         i=1;
     if(k==0){
           k=1;
           sql.append(" email like '"+email+"'");
     }else{
        k=1;
        sql.append("and email like '"+email+"'");
      }
      }
          if(!(doentered.equals(null)||doentered.equals("")))
    {
           i=1;
        if(k==0){
        k=1;
        sql.append(" doentered = '"+doentered+"'");
        }else{
        k=1;
        sql.append("and doentered = '"+doentered+"'");
            }
    }
           if(!(yostudy.equals(null)||yostudy.equals("")))
    {
        i=1;
        if(k==0){
        k=1;
        sql.append(" yostudy like '"+yostudy+"'");
        }else{
        k=1;
        sql.append("and yostudy like '"+yostudy+"'");
            }
    }
            if(!(college.equals(null)||college.equals("")))
    {
        i=1;
        if(k==0){
        k=1;
        sql.append(" college like '"+college+"'");
             }else{
        k=1;
        sql.append("and college like '"+college+"'");
        }
    }

    if(i==1)
            {
                sql.insert(27, " where ");
    }

              String sqlquery=sql.toString();

    now query is ready to execute........
```

Comment: No offense, but that code looks horrible.
Please use parameterized queries to achieve what you want!
Else your sql is vulnerable to SQL injections.
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html